# Core Data Concurrency - Collection was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm adding some objects called `Transaction`s in my Core Data application. Those transactions are linked to an account.

I'd like to update the account amount when all the transactions are saved. Sometimes there is a concurrency exception

> "Collection was mutated while being enumerated"

at `NSArray *matches = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` line in `accountManagedObjectWithId` method.

```
//TransactionsManager

- (BOOL)addRepeatTransaction:(Transaction *)transaction{

    Account *accountTrx = transaction.account;
    double accountAmount = accountTrx.amount;
    for (int i =0; i<nbRepeat; i++){
         accountAmount +=transactionBiz.amount;
        [[Persister instance] registerTransaction:transaction];
    }
    [[Persister instance]editAmountAccount:transaction.account amount:accountAmount];
    [[Persister instance]saveContext];

    return YES;
}

//Persister

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]){
        managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(BOOL)registerTransaction:(Transaction *)transaction {
    TransactionManagedObject *transactionsRow = (TransactionsManagedObject *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transactions" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    transactionsRow.idTransaction =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:transaction.idTransaction];
    transactionsRow.name = transaction.name;
    transactionsRow.amount = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:transaction.amount];
    [...]
    transactionsRow.account = [[Finder instance] accountManagedObjectWithId:transaction.account.idAccount];

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)editAmountAccount:(Account *)asset amount:(double)amount {
    AccountManagedObject *accountRow = [[Finder instance] accountManagedObjectWithId:account.idAccount];

    accountRow.amount = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:amount];
    return YES;
}

-(AccountManagedObject *)accountManagedObjectWithId:(NSInteger)idAccount {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Accounts" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

    //Predicate
    NSString *recordedIdAccount = @"idAccount";
    NSNumber *numberIdAccount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idAccount];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", recordedIdAccount,numberIdAccount];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    //Execute
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matches = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSInteger nbResult = [matches count];
    if(nbResult==1){
        return [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if(nbResult==0){
        [...]
        return nil;
    }
    if(nbResult>0){
        [...]
        return nil;
    }
    return nil;
}

//UI call
[...]
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
     //Save
     [[TransactionsManager instance] addRepeatTransaction:transactionToAdd];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          //Call the delegate
          [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnTheAddTransactionTVCWasTapped:self];
      });
});
```

---

@Valentin Radu

I've tried that but the problem remains. I have to set up a `managedObjectContext` for each adding. This is working but it slows the application. Is it the right way to do it?

```
-(BOOL)registerTransaction:(Transaction *)transaction{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
   [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];


    TransactionsManagedObject *transactionsRow = (TransactionsManagedObject *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transactions" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    transactionsRow.idTransaction =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:transaction.idTransaction];
    transactionsRow.name = transaction.name;
    transactionsRow.amount = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:transaction.amount];
    [...]
    transactionsRow.account = [[Finder instance] accountManagedObjectWithId:transaction.account.idAccount andManagedContext:moc]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![moc save:&error]) {
        [[ErrorManager instance] addError:error];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a self contained answer? Too much details here. Where is your background thread? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be using only one context, which is wrong if you have parallel operations executing on your core data objects. You should have a context per thread and merge the contexts every time you save. Apple's Core Data Guideline talks about this in more detail.

Comment: I've tried that but the problem remains. I have to set up a managedObjectContext for each adding. This is working but it slows the application. Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: Yeah, it is working. My mistake I had tried your solution but not in the right way so I thought that it wasn't woking. Correct me if I'm wrong but the backgroundManagedContext has to be used AND created on the second thread and can't be created on the main thread and used on the second thread?

Comment: @ValentinRadu According to the documentation it does matter on what thread the context is created: "You must create the managed context on the thread on which it will be used." http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html