# Managing concurrency with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency

I'm having problems when managing the insertion of large amount of objects into database through `Core Data`, I get an error like this:

> *** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17ad6110> was mutated while being enumerated.

I've read in several posts that managing concurrency with `Core Data` is needed to avoid this (e.g. [Core Data Concurrency - Collection was mutated while being enumerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805013/core-data-concurrency-collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated)), but the concurrency's chapter in [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) says:

> Important: Best practices for concurrency with Core Data have changed dramatically since this document was written; please note that this chapter does not represent current recommendations.

Which are the current best practices? Where could I find an updated document or tutorial to manage this?

Thanks

Comment: Error message is quite clear. You are enumerating an Entity and while it’s being enumerated you try to insert new record into same Entity. If it’s not your case - give some example source code.

Comment: I know why I get that error message and it is due to a concurrency issue, but I do not know how should I handle it, since `Core Data Programming Guide` seems to be deprecated regarding concurrency...

Comment: You need to show some code to be helped on this platform. Your hypothesis that a deprecated documentation document plays a role in your problem has been understood - no need to repeat it.